Cannot import file globals.scss for new layout.tsx
I have a problem when creating a new layout.tsx file in (auth) folder, when I import the globals.scss file I can't apply the styles to the whole web. Please let me know where the issue is. Thanks all.
This is my structure folder

the new layout.tsx file
import '@/public/styles/globals.scss';
import { MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
import { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Login',
    description: 'Login',
};

export default function SecondLayout({
    children,
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
    return (
        <html lang='en' data-mantine-color-scheme='light'>
            <body>
                <MantineProvider defaultColorScheme='light'>{children}</MantineProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}


Not sure I understand the question - are you saying the globals.scss is not applied to the whole website and that is what you want ?

There is some error in your folder structure. You added styles folder inside public directory. Add it in the root directory of the project as:
  app
   ...
  public
   ...
  styles
   globals.scss

and Import it as:
@/styles/global.scss 



